# getting file from windows ssh server from java

Tags: java, windows, ssh, sftp

I am trying to display file from windows into java. I configured ssh for my windows and try to get file, I can read the file from putty using

cd /Program Files (x86)/Syslogd/Logs

TYPE SyslogCatchAll-2016-11-22.txt

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException,IOException,SftpException {



          JSch jsch = new JSch();
          Session s;
          s = jsch.getSession("host", "192.168.1.2", 22);

          s.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          s.setPassword("host");  
          s.connect();


          ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) s.openChannel("sftp");
          sftpChannel.connect();
          System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");
          InputStream out= null;
          sftpChannel.cd("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Syslogd\\Logs");
          sftpChannel.get("SyslogCatchAll-2016-11-22.txt");
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));
          String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
         {
          System.out.println(line);
           }
          br.close();
         sftpChannel.disconnect();'
```

output

```
SFTP Channel created.
Exception in thread "main" 2: No such file
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._realpath(ChannelSftp.java:2367)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:342)
at fyp.Fyp.main(Fyp.java:53)
```

Comment: Your path is not absolute. `C:\` is not there. How you missed it :) ?

Comment: You mean like this "C:/Program Files (x86)/Syslogd/Logs", I just tried still not working

Answer (score 0):

So I tried this as path "/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/Syslogd/Logs" and it works, but not sure how?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your SSH server, so we cannot answer that. Though this may give you some idea: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_remote_drive

Comment: I installed openSSH on my windows. and created another user to connect.

Comment: There are many ports of OpenSSH for Windows. Which one did you use?